# a transaction with a check if records already exist

Tags: delphi

The code is here. Works OK but I just dont know how to write
a transactions that would be more appropriate for the job (commit,rollback...).

```
procedure TForm1.cxButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with acrquery2 do
  begin
    ACRQuery1.DisableControls;
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('INSERT INTO dnevnik (datum,izmena_id,opravilo,narejeno,sprememba) SELECT :a1,izmena_id,opravilo,narejeno,sprememba FROM opravila where izmena_id = :a2');
    Params.ParamByName('a1').asdate := cxdateedit1.Date;
    Params.ParamByName('a2').AsInteger := acrtable1.FieldByName('izmena_id').AsInteger;
    ACRQuery2.ExecSQL;
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('UPDATE OPRAVILA SET NAREJENO=False,sprememba=null');
    ACRQuery2.ExecSQL;
    ACRQuery1.EnableControls;
    ACRQuery1.Refresh;
  end;
```

I would like to wrap the above code in a transaction but first do a check before insertion if "datum" and "izmena_id" already exist in the "dnevnik" table (duplicates are not allowed). If they do, then abort the operation with a message. I dont know the SQL for such a check. Probably 'if exists' ...

In SQLite it was easy with setting constraints but dont know with Accuracer. Can someone help me write this code right ? Thank you !

Comment: Seeing as Accuracer is a single-file proprietary database, you might get the best answer from its publisher, AidAim.  Have you tried asking them?

Comment: "*In SQLite it was easy with setting constraints*" - Accuracer supports Unique Indexes to prevent inserting duplicate values.

Comment: If you want to check if the *values* of `datum,izmena_id` exist, you can just write a select query.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - It seems I can not do with indexes because the query inserts multiple records with 'datum' and izmena_id' which are the same. Setting those to unique will only insert one record.Jan - can you show me an example ?

Comment: "*I would like to ... do a check before insertion if "datum" and "izmena_id" already exist in the "dnevnik" table (duplicates are not allowed)*" - that is exactly what a unique constraint does. You do not need to check manually. If you try to insert duplicate values with a unique constraint in place, an error will occur that you can handle as needed.